# AVPlayer Lock Screen Controls

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have an app that plays audio on the background using AVPlayer. I use MPNowPlayingInfoCenter to display the song's metadata on the Lock Screen and Control Center. Everything works fine except for one thing.

The remote controls on the Lock Screen and Control Center are those of a podcast app. They don't have forward and previous buttons.

I have a screenshot of how the controls are:

[image]

As you can see, I don't have forward and previous buttons.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

@IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {

    if isURLAvailable == false {
        return
    }

    if (player!.rate != 0 && player!.error == nil) {
        player!.pause()
    } else {
        player!.play()
    }
        updateImage()
}

func playSong(song: Song) {

    let documentsDirectoryURL =  NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as NSURL?
    let url: NSURL? = documentsDirectoryURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(song.fileName)

    let avItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url!)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: avItem)

    player?.play()

    let artworkProperty = MPMediaItemArtwork(image: song.artwork)
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyTitle : lblSongName.text!, MPMediaItemPropertyArtist : song.artist, MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork : artworkProperty, MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyDefaultPlaybackRate : NSNumber(int: 1), MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration : CMTimeGetSeconds((player!.currentItem?.asset.duration)!)]

}

override func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(event: UIEvent?) {
    print(event!.type)
    if event!.type == UIEventType.RemoteControl {
        if event?.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPlay || event?.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPause {
            play(self)
        }
        if event?.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlNextTrack {
            next(self)
        }
        if event?.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPreviousTrack {
            previous(self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be useful to see what code you have currently implemented.

Comment: Actually, those are the controls of an audio book, not a podcast, aren't they?

Comment: Where is the code that allows the lock screen to control _your_ app? None of the code you have shown would do that. So my guess so far would be that the buttons are for some other app (like iBooks).

Comment: @matt see the updated question

Comment: Nope, I'm not seeing any relevant code.

Comment: Nope. You're not making yourself first responder. You have not persuaded me that the lock screen is connecting to your app.

Comment: @matt Even with overriding canBecomeFirstResponder,  it seems to have no effect on the app's behavior.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rather than using the `UIEvent` stream with `remoteControlReceivedWithEvent`, I would recommend you use `MPRemoteCommandCenter` to control the previous/next/play/pause actions on the lock screen and control center.

```
import MediaPlayer

// ...

let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.sharedCommandCenter()

commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.enabled = true;
commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: "previousTrack")

commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.enabled = true
commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: "nextTrack")

commandCenter.playCommand.enabled = true
commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget(self, action: "playAudio")

commandCenter.pauseCommand.enabled = true
commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: "pauseAudio")
```

Where `previousTrack`, `nextTrack`, `playAudio`, and `pauseAudio` are all functions in your class where you control the player.

You may need to explicitly disable the skip forward and backward commands as well:

```
commandCenter.skipBackwardCommand.enabled = false
commandCenter.skipForwardCommand.enabled = false
```

Comment: Elegant but is it relevant?

Comment: I'm glad you answered, Although the problem is still present. Perhaps an OS bug?

Comment: @matt If I recall from the Apple docs, `MPRemoteCommandCenter` is the better way to handle events like this rather than using `remoteControlReceivedWithEvent` (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html).  If I'm wrong please feel free to correct me and add your own alternative answer.

Comment: @JAL No, I agree with you! But I still think the reason why your suggestion works is that he was never making himself first responder so there was in fact no connection between the lock screen / control center and his app. The MPRemoteCommandCenter registration provides a one-step reliable way to set up the same connection. So when he switched to it, things started working.

Comment: There's a typo: `commandCenter.playCommand.enabled = true
commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: "playAudio")`  It should say `playCommand.addTarget` instead.