# How is MPChangePlaybackRateCommand triggered?

Tags: ios, mpremotecommandcenter

I'm playing around with the audio features in iOS, and I'm looking at [`MPRemoteCommandCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpremotecommandcenter?language=objc)'s `changePlaybackRateCommand`. I have enabled it, given it a target, and set its `supportedPlaybackRates`, but I don't see any related UI showing up in control center or the lock screen. And other commands I've set up, like skip forward, skip back, like, dislike, and bookmark, show up properly.

How does a user trigger a `MPChangePlaybackRateCommand` on iOS?

Comment: I face this problem and I found palybackrate does not work with other people but i found something strange i found rate icon in Apple watch and i can change the rate from it when i use podcast app

Comment: Did you find an answer, yet?

Answer (score 0):

I face this problem and when I search I get other people face the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34008395/3806350)

but I found something strange when I play podcast app in apple watch I found rate icon and I change the playrate from  it

[image]

I think it's not work in iPhone (iPhone 6 iOS 11 ) but appear and work in another Apple devices in my case Apple watch

in iOS example [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/MPRemoteCommandSample/Introduction/Intro.html) Apple not add `MPChangePlaybackRateCommand` like other commands that make me sure about it's bug in iOS